# Add to contents of vector to use in an RJDBC query

Tags: r, concatenation, vertica

I'm using a RJDBC connection to query results from a vertica database into R.  I'm creating a comma separated vector of zip codes that I'm then pasting into my query as shown below.

```
b <- paste("'20882'", "'01441'", "'20860'", "'02139'", sep = ", ")

SQL <- paste("select zip, count(*)
from tablea a 
inner join tableb b on a.id = b.id
inner join tablec c on c.col = b.col
where b.zip in (",b'', ") group by 1 order by 1", '', sep = " ")

result <- dbGetQuery(vertica, SQL)
```

I'm using this in a loop within a function in which I'm going to be adding zip codes to vector b.  I was wondering if there was a way to easily do this?

I've been trying, but I'm unable to add items to vector in a way where the query would execute.

Something like the following

```
b <- c(add_zip, b)
```

which could then be re-run in the body of the query.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: The question isn't clear. Are you trying to append zip codes to the string or the character vector before it's collapsed into a string? Assuming that you have all your zip codes in a character vector, you can collapse that vector into a string using paste with the collapse argument: `b <- paste(zip_vector, collapse = ", ")`, where `zip_vector <- c("'20882'", "'01441'", "'20860'")`. If you want to append to the string, you can use paste: `paste(b, new_zip, sep=", ")` where `new_zip <- "'20882'"`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  I understand what you're saying.

If I'm grabbing new zip from a dataframe with it in character format, how would I add the quotes and apostrophes around it?

eg.  new_zip <- zips[1,] might give me "20882".  How can I make it become "'20882'"

Comment: You can use `paste` or `paste0` for that (`paste0` is a special and more efficient instance of `paste` where the `sep` argument is ""). The following achieves what you need to do: `paste0("'", "20882", "'")` or `paste("'", "20882", "'", sep="")`.